# Show that map $F: \prod_{t\in T} X_t \rightarrow \prod_{t\in T} Y_t$ where $(F(x))_t = f_t(x_t)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X_t, Y_t$ be topological spaces. Maps $f_t: X_t \rightarrow Y_t$ are continuous for every $t \in T$.

Show, that map $F: \prod_{t\in T} X_t \rightarrow \prod_{t\in T} Y_t$ defined as $(F(x))_t = f_t(x_t)$ is continuous.

First of all, I'd like to show that $(F(x))_t: \prod_{t\in T}X_t \rightarrow Y_t$ is a continuous map for every $t\in T$.

Observe that $(F(x))_t = (f_t \circ \pi^X_t)(x)$ where $\pi^X_t$ is a projection $\prod_{t\in T} X_t \rightarrow X_t$. Since both $f_t$ and $\pi^X_t$ are continuous, we deduce continuity of $(F(x))_t$.

Now, from the theorem which states that "$f:Y\rightarrow \prod_{s\in S}X_s$ is continuous if and only if for every $s \in S$, $\pi_s \circ f$ is continuous"

In our case, $\pi^Y_t \circ F = F_t$ which is continuous for every $t\in T$.
Hence, by theorem above we receive continuity of map $F$.

Is it correct? If it's not, would be a pleasure to get some hints.

Comment: Looks good! $\,$